# Critical points and extrema of $\sin (3x)$ on $[-\pi/4,\pi/3]$

Tags: calculus

> a) Find the critical points, if any, of the following function on the given interval.
>
> b) Determine the absolute extreme values of $f$ on the given interval.
>
> c) Use a graphing utility to confirm your conclusions.
>
> $$f(x)=\sin(3x)\quad\text{on }\left[-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi3\right]$$

I Know $f'(x)= 3\cos(3x)$. However, I'm not sure how to determine the zeros for $x$ for a trig function.

so,

Im asuming becuase $pi/2$ is the only zero of a cos funtion is between the interval of  $[-\pi/4,\pi/3]$ ; then 3x = $\pi/2$

therfore x = $3pi/2$ is the only critical point. and if it is the only critical point is the only extreme as well.

however still not sure how to answer this question

Comment: What's a critical point? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? If you are having trouble using your graphing calculator, what sort of trouble is it?

Comment: a critical point is were the first derivative equals zero and not in the domain or given interval. This should not be a new concept for someone able to answer a calculus question?

Comment: You have given no prior indication that you understood such concepts as "function" or "zero". We like to see what effort you have already put in to solve the problem before we help. Have you, say, *calculated* the first derivative?

Comment: problem is the fact that the question is a trig is were I got stuck: if f'(x)= 3cos(3x) how do I set that equal to zero and solve for the zero's for x?

Comment: Well, what are the zeros of the cosine function?

Comment: pi/2 and 3pi/2 ...i think?

Comment: Those are among them, but there are more! What is $\cos(\theta+2\pi n)$, when $n$ is an integer?

Comment: I'm assuming that all the angels on the unit circle where x equals zero would be included. 90deg 270deg 450deg ...and so on

Comment: not sure how to answer what cos(theata + 2pi n) is... :(

Comment: What happens when you add/subtract $2\pi$ radians to an angle?

Comment: it moves by 360 degrees

Comment: Yes, and what does that do to its sine and cosine?

Comment: it remains the same

Comment: You should now have enough information to figure out this question. Why don't you scroll down and write your own answer? We can then critique it.

Comment: Ill give it a try... but still not sure i know what im doing :/

Comment: well I tryed to answer by editing the question since I cant answer my own question here... but I still am lost

Comment: You're on the right track, but you're restricting things to the interval too early in the game.

Comment: wells... thanks for the help thus far. I did learn something. however I'm done. I've spent 3 plus hrs trying to learn how do do this problem... and I got 20 more to do like it. I know your trying to make me learn but without a example or something I think my brain  is going to burst.

Answer (score 0):

Find the first few positive zeros of the cosine and the first few negative ones.

Use those to find the first few positive zeros of $f'$ and the first few negative ones.

Which of those lie in the interval you're interested in?